# Is there a smart way to parrallelize complex functions on ndarray?

Tags: python, performance, parallel-processing, list-comprehension, statsmodels

There exist a wide range of possibilities in `python` to give your code performance a boost (e.g. broadcasting, packages like [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/). But as far as I know these methods rely on the code being *basic* in a sense that e.g. `numpy.ndarray` or functions of `numpy.linalg` are used.

In my particular case I'm using [statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html) [ThetaModel](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.forecasting.theta.ThetaModel.html) to forecast (many!) time series which are grouped in an `ndarray`.

**Is there any smart way to boost code performance/parallelize the code?**

For the moment I'm using list comprehension.

---

#### (Simplified) Working Example

```py
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.forecasting.theta import ThetaModel

def thetaForecast(series):
    model = ThetaModel(series, period=50, deseasonalize=True, use_test=False).fit()
    forecast = model.forecast(steps=len(series))
    return forecast
    
data = np.random.randn(500,10) # 10 time series each of length 500 (dimensions reduced here for simplification)
dataForecast = np.array([thetaForecast(col) for col in data.transpose()])
```

Just in case it plays a role, my function `thetaForecast` actually needs more than one parameter in contrast to this slightly simplified version.

PS: I'm not an experienced stackoverflow user. Tips for how to improve my question are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using multiprocessing?  Unless ThetaModel.forecast() releases the GIL (which it could if it's implemented in C or Fortran), multiprocessing is the main way you can parallelize this.

Or of course you could reimplement forecast() yourself in Numba, C, C++, or Fortran and release the GIL yourself--then you could use multiple threads in a single process.